# Elegant way to populate the dropdown with ajax Without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Can anyone help me to solve this problem I want to populate the dropdown with ajax. when I insert data in database I want it to display on the select option  without refreshing .This dropdown is not based on other dropdown. There is no other dropdown. only a single Dropdown.

html

```
 <select name="id" id="id"></select>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bedrooms(){
        $('#id').empty();
        $('#id').append("<option>loading........</option>");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"checking_database.php",
            contentType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                $('#id').empty();
                $.each(data,function(i,item){
                    $('#id').append('<option>"'+data[i].number_of_bedrooms+'"</option>');
                });
            },
            complete:function(){
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        bedrooms();
    });
</script>
```

checking_database.php

```
<?php
$data = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","price");   
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from bedroom");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $data[] = array("number_of_bedrooms" => $row['number_of_bedrooms']); 
    };
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Output

[image]

Required output: show the data as a option without refresing.

Can anyone tell me the answer how i resolve this problem.i am in learning phase of the ajax and the php. i also google about it but i found the dropdown which based on each other.Thank You

Comment: What is the problem with the code that you have posted in your question?

Comment: @Turnip the dropdown don't show the values without refresing

Comment: Your PHP is returning an array of numbers yet your javascript is trying to access the `id` property of an object: `item.id`. Your browsers console is probably displaying an error message.

Comment: _" without refresing"_ - nothing in the code shown would cause a page refresh. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i want the data from data base in the select option without any refresh. can you tell me sir how can i do this. @Turnip

Comment: As i just said; nothing in the code shown would cause the page to refresh.

Comment: sir,Actually i am not getting you properly. Can you write a code to keep me out from this problem?@Turnip

Comment: sir,see i edit my question for you

Comment: @Puneet in order to refresh the contents of the `select` you need to call `bedrooms()`... So if I understood you correctly, in order to have some sort of realtime display you'd need to poll the server periodically with something like `setInterval(bedrooms, 3000)`

Comment: thank you @ManuelOtto. You made my day but there is a small doubt can i tell?

Comment: @Puneet go ahead.

Comment: @ManuelOtto its look like a select option is shivering . can i stop it. means can i still this shivering.

Comment: @Puneet yes, you could perhaps store the previously received data in a variable and check if the newly received data is different from the previous data, and only then update the select's html.

Comment: can you please write some code for it it help me alot. @ManuelOtto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var last_bedroom_data
function bedrooms(){
    if(!last_bedroom_data){
        $('#id').empty();
        $('#id').append("<option>loading........</option>");
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"checking_database.php",
        contentType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(last_bedroom_data==JSON.stringify(data)) // data is the same
                return; // skip rendering of html
            updateBedroomSelect(data);
            last_bedroom_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        complete:function(){
        }
    });
}
function updateBedroomSelect(data){
    $('#id').empty();
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
       $('#id').append('<option>"'+data[i].number_of_bedrooms+'"</option>');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    bedrooms();
    setInterval(bedrooms,3000);
});
```

Comment: @Puneet it loads at first, but then doesnt refresh if you change the database entries?

Comment: sir it doesn't work. when it reload first then only `loading........`    will display nothing else @manuelotto and when I remove the return statement it works but the value will changes after **3000** (means when i select the value it shanges to the initial value  `2` after 3000)

Comment: i appreciate your answer nice. can you told me how it works?

Comment: @Puneet as already said, it checks for changes in the data and only then calls `updateBedroomSelect` which changes the `select`'s html. the `if(!last_bedroom_data)` makes sure the `loading.......` is only displayed once, when the select is still empty.